# Can you fire a "Disposing" event if Dispose() is called by a Finalizer?

Tags: c#, events, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

I've noticed there are some classes on MSDN ([like this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.disposing.aspx)) that have a `Disposing` event with the following comment:

> Occurs when Dispose is called or when this object is finalized and collected by the garbage collector.

I'd like to implement my own `Disposing` event in a class of mine.  Here's my basic implementation ([following the best practices for the dispose pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
public abstract class Handle : IDisposable
{
    public bool Disposed { get; private set; }

    public event System.Action DisposingCompleted;

    public Handle()
    {
        Disposed = false;
    }

    ~Handle()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing = false)
    {
        if (Disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            HandleManagedResources();
        }

        HandleUnManagedResources();

        Disposed = true;

        if (DisposingCompleted != null)
        {
            DisposingCompleted();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void HandleManagedResources() {}
    protected virtual void HandleUnManagedResources() {}
}
```

Someone mentioned on my Code Review that they're unsure of whether or not firing an event like this is safe because `Dispose()` might get called from the finalizer but, according to the comments on that MSDN link I've added at the top, it's clear that there are objects firing events when they're Disposed OR Finalized.

Am I missing something or is this safe?  How does [GraphicsDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.disposing.aspx) implement an event that's fired from dispose OR when finalized? If the answer is just "No, you can't do this ever" then is there any other way of achieving the same effect? (an event for an object being disposed *OR* finalized)

Comment: You should use the standard suggested implementation and pattern, like naming and conventions, instead of rolling your own. In particular, you should use `bool disposing` instead of `bool fromFinalizer`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sure, I changed the names around.

Comment: You might want to read Eric Lipperts post about all the weirdness that can happen in finalizers http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/

Comment: Never, *never* raise the event when *disposing* is false.  You cannot afford to have arbitrary code running from the finalizer, the odds that it doesn't cause problems are very low.  A *Disposing* event is only reasonable when you have a decent guarantee that the Dispose() method is going to be called.  That tends to be hard to come by.unless the class object is completely under your control.

Comment: @HansPassant How how does the `GraphicsDevice` implement an event that can be fired when disposed *or* finalized?  It's implemented by Microsoft; I'd imagine if there was an issue with it it would be noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to do anything involving other objects in the `Dispose` methods you should only do so when `Dispose` is called explicitly, not when it is called from the finalizer.

The reason for this is that if that other object too is eligible for collection you have no guarantee that that object hasn't already been finalized.

Comment: So how does something like the `GraphicsDevice` I linked have an event that it says is fired "when Dispose is called or when this object is finalized"?  What if I can guarantee that the subscribers will live longer than the publishers?

Comment: You can easily write the code to do it, but it is not recommended nor necessarily safe to do.

Comment: So I'm confused as to how it's implemented by classes Microsoft has made.  I find it hard to believe functionality built into the XNA framework like `GraphicsDevice` and `StorageContainer` managed to do so but don't note anywhere that those events aren't safe to use.  If the answer is just "No, you can't do this ever" then is there any other way of achieving the same effect?

Comment: I didn't say you *can't* do this. I said you shouldn't. You're asking a general question, you will get a general answer. If you have specific classes in mind that you can program in such a way that calling Dispose on a finalized object is guaranteed to be safe then go for it. The *general recommendation* is to not do it.

Comment: If you manage to crash the finalization thread, your application might be doomed.

Comment: If you can implement the Disposing event in such a way that you don't tie the lifetime of the object being disposed to the object on which the event handler will fire then that would work. It would, however, involve creating some way of holding on to the event even though your own object is going to be collected, so a static event handler. This is not recommended for other reasons, such as easy to create memory leaks.

Comment: Alright, thanks Lasse.  You've given me enough information to work through this.  I also found that Monogame's implementation of `StorageContainer` doesn't actually fire the event when `Dispose` is called from the finalizer.(https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/ae2aa622ee956d057d9f3a93230eac98c5a3101f/MonoGame.Framework/Storage/StorageContainer.cs)